Identifying IBM PC SIMM RAM size
I am trying to restore an IBM-compatible pc from the mid-90s. I have some SIMM ram blocks I could use, but I have no clue on how to identify the ram size. Any help would be appreciated.
Edit: picture


Do they have any markings on the chips, on the board, etc?

Start with (a) make sure the SIMMs physically fit the motherboard. Assuming they do (because it they don't it is hopeless - the different pin configurations correspond to vastly different types/speeds/etc.), please add (b) the make/model of the computer or motherboard, or if you don't have that then pictures of the motherboard and (c) pictures of the SIMMs.

You identify SIMM Size by type (written on the chip) and number of individual RAM chips on the SIMM. Without knowing that, nobody will be able to help you.

Each chip on the 3rd one down is marked 1M (bit) x 16 and I assume 60nS.  So that's 4MB total EDO RAM.

For the rest - start googling part numbers.

Do the SIMMs have chips on only one side, or both sides? Some are single rank and some are dual rank. And if those SIMMs are from HP printers they may have non-standard presence detect.

they have chips on both sides. they are not from a priter but from an olivetti new m24 with a 100mhz pentium.

The general approach seems to be to find information on the individual chips and then multiply by the number of chips. It won't give you compatibility but it will give you capacity if you can find the information.
Like: "This chip is a 1 Mbit DRAM and there's two of them, so that's 2048 KBits or 256 KB per module."

The SIMMs pictured are 72-pin SIMMs (the bottom example is conveniently labelled as such on the PCB, even if you didn't recognise them by sight). 72-pin SIMMs have a 32-bit data interface with their sockets and the motherboard (compared with 16 its for the older 30-pin SIMMs, and more bits for later DIMMs.
Individual RAM chips will have address lines to access some number of memory locations, and each memory location (or word) will store a number of bits of data. Even though we think of memory in terms of 8-bit bytes, RAM chips can have different arrangements - and often do. The manufacturer of these 72-pin SIMMs will have wired the RAM chips do that they provide 32 bits of data at a time (e.g. two 16-bit chips side by side), with any extra chips mapped to different memory addresses to increase the SIMM's memory capacity.
The third SIMM, with chips labelled 1Mx16-60 is a good example of the structure of a RAM chip. It has 1 Mega addresses, each of which store 16 bits of data, i.e. 16 Megabits. Divide this figure by 8, and we find that this RAM chip provides 2 Megabytes of RAM. There are two chips visible on the upper side, and I assume there are another two on the lower side based on the shadows. (There can't be three chips, as the 16 Megabit chips need to be wired in pairs to provide 32 bits of data to the SIMM slot.) Four chips would mean the third SIMM has a capacity of 2x4=8 Megabytes. The -60 label indicates the time in nanoseconds the RAM needs to fetch/store data: shorter times mean the RAM can be run faster if the motherboard and processor support it.
For the other chips, we need to look up the manufacturer part numbers for the RAM chips. The first SIMM has four TMS418169ADZ chips (two top and bottom). A search for datasheets online tells me these are also 1Mx16 chips, so will have the same 8 Megabyte capacity as the third SIMM.
The chip markings on the second SIMM are not clearly legible in the photograph provided, but the SIMM as a whole looks to be identical to the first (so I guess it's another 8MB SIMM).
The fourth SIMM has four HYM322005S-60 chips. A datasheet search with this part number tells me they're 2Mx32 chips, with 64Mbits or 8Mbytes of RAM per chip. With four chips, that'll be a total of 32 Megabytes of RAM on this SIMM.
